# jQuery and Prototype events

Tags: jquery, dom, prototypejs, dom-events

I have a Prototype code that is triggered upon 'load' event:

```
  Event.observe($(imageEl), 'load', this.someFunction.bind(this));
```

When I create 'Real' event using jQuery code like

```
  jQuery(...imageEl selector...).attr("src", filename);
```

it fires the Prototype code (someFunction). *Good!*

Next I try to fire the Prototype code using jQuery trigger:

```
  jQuery(...imageEl selector...).trigger('load');
```

But now, nothing happen i.e. this line doesn't fire the Prototype code.

Any idea **how to trigger a Prototype event from jQuery?**

Comment: Why are you using both libraries? And why can't you just trigger the event from Prototype?

Comment: Of course if I would write my code from scratch I would only use jQuery. Unfortunately I have to integrate an old code based on Prototype + Scriptaculous with new code based on jQuery. Both codes reacts to external events! 

Specifically, jQuery/UI "resizable" changes the size of DOM object(s) whose children are managed by the old Scriptaculous-based code for zooming (using Scriptaculous slider etc.).

I kind of solved the problem using the DOMAttrModified event. I use this in jQuery:

  jQuery(...).attr({...});

to trigger this:

  Event.observe(..., 'DOMAttrModified', ... );

Cheers,
Sty

Answer (score 2):

You should call your handler directly passing required arguments or trigger the **native DOM event**.

NOTE: prototype's fire and jquery's trigger create custom events, not native.

Read the following answers on how to trigger native events:

- [trigger-an-event-with-prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype)
- [javascript-event-that-fires-without-user-interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590289/javascript-event-that-fires-without-user-interaction/590339#590339)