# Does calling `click()` in jQuery only trigger jQuery attached events?

Tags: jquery, magento, prototypejs, lightbox, dom-events

I have a Magento site, which includes the prototype JavaScript library.

Some time ago, I added jQuery as well.

Before that however, I'd included a prototype based Lightbox. It was triggered by adding the attribute `rel="lightbox[gallery]"`.

Now I'd like to make a lightbox appear on page load. I know *nothing* about prototype, so I tried creating a hidden link with jQuery and then calling `$('#special').click()` but to no avail. If I actually click the link however, it works fine.

*All* my jQuery code is in a function like so

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(function($) {
 // Now I can use $ in here... :)

});
```

So does jQuery's `click()` only trigger events that jQuery has binded? If so, how could I call the click event or trigger the lightbox in prototype?

Comment: check if you're not having conflicts because of the $() shortcut

Comment: Regarding the last edit: AFAIK, prototype.js *used to* do some dodgy stuff like that (modifying Object.prototype), but I'm fairly certain they've dropped that brain-damage by now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So does jQuery's click() only trigger events that jQuery has binded?

It will also trigger events bound via old-style `onEventName` attributes. But it *won't* trigger events bound via `addEventListener()` or `attachEvent()` (which, AFAIK, are what Prototype uses to bind events...)

However, you *can* simulate an actual click event. It'll just take a bit more effort...

#### See: [How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag)

#### See also: [Trigger an event with Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype)

Comment: I tried doing this (re: prototype custom click) but did not work `var p = $; p('special').simulate(`click`);`

Comment: Produced an error. `simulate` not a method of $. I placed the `var p` above the `jQuery.noConflict()` so I could hopefully still reference prototype from inside the `jQuery(function($) { });`.

Comment: @alex: Oh... Well, then you probably need to include the event.simulate.js linked to in that second question. ;-) That or just use the script in the first question.

Comment: Sorry, yeah I did do that. I'm just gonna take a break from it for a while. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. use "jQuery" instead of "$". Function $ is defined in both Prototype and jQuery.
   it is possible you're trying to call "click()" method on Prototype-selected object, which may not work ( I don't know prototype at all, except that it defines "$" function as well)
   ( note: please have a look at http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries )
2. This does not exactly answer your question, but why don't you use lightbox for jQuery? ;)
   http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: See update. Also, for 2, I've already implemented the Prototype lightbox throughout the site. I want to stick with it (for now).

Answer (score 0):

When using jquery, try using jQuery [noconflict](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) so that by default `$` refers to protoype and using `jQuery` when you want to use jQuery. To be honest in my experience when ever I added two frameworks and tried to make them work together it's always a problem and almost near hell. What special are you trying to achieve using jQuery in a project made with prototype?

Comment: I am taking care of conflicts. I included jQuery as well, because I know jQuery, and wanted to get something done (as opposed to learning prototype for one small project)

Comment: I can only back up the one-framework advice. Even with `noconflict` there are loads of confusing little incompatibilities and edge cases.

Answer (score 0):

To use $ as you ask, do this:

```
jQuery(function() {
  (function($) {
    //
    // your initialization code goes in here
    // and you can use '$' safely as the name
    // of the jQuery object, even though
    // window.$ is something else
    //
  })(jQuery);
});
```

Comment: Ah you mean the double-wrapping?  Yes OK, jQuery passes in the jQuery object so it's cool.

Comment: jQuery passes it as the first parameter to the callback, so the way alex is doing it now is fine.

Answer (score 0):

very very easy solution is to append $j = jQuery.noConflict at the end of the jquery source file. then globally you can just use $j and not have to worry about wrapping functions

Comment: Well, when passing $ as an argument like `jQuery(function($) { })`, it means the same thing. Plus I don't have to break habit of using $.

Comment: right but then you are required everytime you use it to wrap...if you use a lot of jquery then it just saves some time in writing scripts.
in my last implementation it is all jquery minus native magento js, so it probably saved a 1000 lines of code by doing it as such. It is by no means the end all solution because there are plenty of ways to do things, just a way to save on some lines of code and make the separation of libraries easily visible.

Comment: I only use it once in this scenario though. But if I was using it throughout the site extensively, I probably would bind the jQuery object to a new variable as suggested by you.