# Firing a click event with Prototype

Tags: javascript, magento, prototypejs

currently working on magento and managed to remove certain sections from the check out process that are not needed. Anyway the last section I want to remove is the order review so essentaly instead of Billing Address > Review > Comfirmation. I just want Billing > Comfirmation. Anyway with in JS I can do this?

My current idea is to assign a id to the finaly submit button. select element and click it once on the review stage atomatically by js.

at moment i modifyed the gotosection code and added.

```
if(orig == 'review'){
 $('reviewButton').click();
}
```

In prototype how do i select a element and use .click() method on it please.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype

Answer (score 3):

You can find the element exactly as in your code:

```
var element = $('reviewButton');
```

Prototype doesn't provide any special means of firing native events on elements, but [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2705583/simulate-click-javascript) here on SO seem to think it's fairly do-able with Javascript.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this :

```
Event.simulateEvent($('reviewButton'),'click');
```