# Trigger Lightbox onLoad w/ Delay

Tags: javascript, lightbox, lightbox2

Does anyone familiar with Lightbox2 (http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/) know how to trigger a lightbox onLoad and preferably with a 1 minute delay?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used some info from another SO post to simulate the click event:
[Trigger an event with Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype)

Get the code from [event.simulate.js](http://github.com/kangax/protolicious/blob/master/event.simulate.js) and include a reference in your file.

```
<script src="js/simulate.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Add an **id** to the anchor link you want to auto-fire:

```
<a href="images/image-1.jpg" id="openLink" rel="lightbox">
```

Then at the bottom of your file insert this code (or put in external file):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function openLightbox() {
        $('openLink').simulate('click');
    }
    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
        openLightbox.delay(5);
    });
</script>
```

The number in the delay() function is the number of seconds you want to wait before the lightbox fires off.

Comment: Thanks Shawn. Simulating a click was a great idea, I actually went ahead and just used Prototypes default click action to simulate a click. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Ok cool, I am not familiar with Prototype and couldn't easily find how they did that.