# when open website - how to load image popup

Tags: jquery, html, popup

when open website - how to load image popup

once website opened a popup image needs to open . auto height and weight.

need close button to close the image.

if click the image is to go another page in another window.

Answer (score 0):

use `window.onload()` and then add your popup.

Comment: window.onload() what javascrpit?

Comment: yes. i think you can use the lightbox plugin. and make it popup onload. haven't tried though. http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/

Comment: oh... not sure about that. thank you. i am new. i will tru to search in google and implement. thank you very much

Comment: have a look at here @BharathSudar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443663/trigger-lightbox-onload-w-delay

Comment: @BharathSudar no you don't. it just simulates a click so that pop-up can be displayed without actual click

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Popup windows can be sufficiently annoying that browsers only allow them to be triggered in response to the user interacting with the page. Arriving at the page is insufficient.

Add the image to the page itself instead.