# Binding and triggering native and custom events in Prototype

Tags: javascript, event-handling, prototypejs, dom-events, custom-events

I'm having a bit of issue with events in prototype.

I'm trying to bind and fire the native events: `onhashchange`, and `onpopstate`. As well as my custom events: `statechange` and `anchorchange`. All these events are for the `window` element.

Here's the code I've already tried with no luck:

```
Element.observe(window,eventName,eventHandler);
Element.fire(window,eventName);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up coming up with this:
https://gist.github.com/796871

Which allows a consistent API for custom and standard events.

Answer (score 2):

You can only use fire for custom events.

[Take a look at this question/answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype)  I think it solves your problem.  It's certainly what we use.

Comment: Thanks, I used it as a basis for my answer :)