# jQuery change() not firing prototype event handlers

Tags: jquery, prototypejs, dom-events

I have an existing prototype codebase that does stuff on selectbox changes...

I have used jQuery that generates (styled) unordered-lists and I wish to proxy clicks to that list to my selectbox... This all works fine (calling `val()` on selectbox), but prototype doesnt pick up on these changes, even when I explicitly call `change()` on the selectbox... Anyone know what is going on?

I could post a bunch of code but it is all very basic, I think the only relevant part is:

> parent_obj.val(selected_idx).change();

Which does change the selected item in my selectbox, but doesn't fire my prototype event handler.

edit:

There will probably be an answer about using trigger() etc... that doesn't seem to work either:

```
parent_obj.val(selected_idx).click().change().trigger('click');
parent_obj.find('option value[' + selected_idx + ']').click().change().trigger('click');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up using prototype Event.simulate as suggested by this answer;

[Trigger an event with Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype)

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem by using a mix of jQuery and vanilla Javascript

```
parent_obj.val(selected_idx);
parent_obj.get(0).dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
```

Answer (score 1):

All `trigger` (or `change`, which is just a shortcut for `trigger('change')`) does is calling the bound jQuery event handlers. Changing a value from javascript does not  trigger handlers either (think of all the infinite loops that could cause!). In general, there is no reliable way of triggering events from javascript. You probably should use a single framework to do your event handling. Otherwise, you should find Prototype's equivalent of `trigger` and call it manually.

Comment: I -am- using a single framework to do event handling. I want to be able to fire one event from the other framework though... Though me saying this is no longer needed, as I have found my answer in the following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype

Event.simulate will suit me just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Likely you need to look at the use of `jQuery.noConflict()` here, then ensure isolation.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

See this post on protype event stuff: [Trigger an event with Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype)

Comment: There is no conflict. Both code work just fine, I am already using noConflict and an anonymous wrapper function for jQuery (function($) { ... })(jQuery); - the problem is in getting prototype event handler to fire after making changes with jQuery.

Comment: It might also help to have a function outside of both that you call from jQuery to trigger the prototype event handler then.

Answer (score 0):

So, the solution is to use "simulate.js" because you cannot fire an event registered on prototype with jQuery.

After struggling some minutes, i realized that in order to "simulate.js" works on select option, it needs to be **selected** the option you want first
In my example i want to the last option would be selected by default

```
$$('select#shipping_method option').last().selected=true;
$$('select#shipping_method option').last().simulate('change');
```

Greetings