# Trigger click jquery not working

Tags: jquery, triggers, pageload

I'm figuring out why this simple script is not working:

```
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.next_button a').trigger('click');
});
```

`noConflict` is necessary because I also load prototype/scriptaculous in this page.

If I replace `.trigger('click')` with another function (es: `.css(...)` this works well. Only triggering seems to go broken.

Comment: Your question is incomplete without a test case that demonstrates the problem. See [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I can't post the website link, sorry, only in private, in case

Comment: What Gary Green answered is probably what you are looking for, but without the rest of the code its impossible to know.

Comment: I understand but I cant post more, thanks anyway

Answer (score 67):

[How can I simulate an anchor click via jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773639/how-can-i-simulate-an-anchor-click-via-jquery)
Check this link and see
[this answer by Stevanicus](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10559680/312594).

`$('a#swaswararedirectlink')[0].click();`

Comment: Can you tell why the `[0]` is necessary?

Comment: [0] gets the first (DOM) element. The .click() function call is calling the browser's built-in 'click' function (not jquery's)

Comment: this should be the accepted answer since it provides a solution, i.e., `[0]`.

Comment: Excellent! Worked fine without errors. I put as  $('a.sliderLinks').trigger('click'); . But not worked. Then I put your code. superb! thanks again.

Comment: damn! why is the [0] necessary? weird that click() doesn't get trigger the other selector, what does "[0] gets the first (DOM) element" do? (Tahir reply)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/YHx2d/ it works fine in this fiddle without [0].... but not on my real page...

Comment: @ah-shiang han Did you try with [0] in your page ?

Comment: yes, with [0] my page works, my question is that why fiddle works without using the [0]... but my page it is required to have [0]. I'm kinda confused. Thanks in advance for explaining

Comment: Its weird how cycling through some elements that i need clicked (opening links in new tabs) only works once... NO IDEA why...

Comment: Really Helpful answer. Need to accept it. @Riccardo Thanks buddy +1

Answer (score 50):

You can only trigger a click that jQuery has created. It's one of jQuery's cute little quirks.

Comment: Good advice, i.e. use the trigger method AFTER you've established the click listener

Comment: Not only that, Pete but this also means default anchor tag use

Comment: +1 YOU! This saved me from breaking my desk and throwing out my computer!  A note to people who may be working with backbone + requirejs. If your trigger events on UI elements are not working, you may just have a handle on the wrong jquery object wherever you are calling it.

Comment: Trigger after Listener. Trigger AFTER listener. Hours wasted until I found this out. +1 @PeteHerbertPenito

Comment: That helped. Thanks

Answer (score 12):

as what Gary has answered. the code below will not work.

```
$('#border_wrap').trigger('click');    
$('#border_wrap').click(function(e){
    console.log("clicked1");
});
```

but this will.. :)

```
$('#border_wrap').click(function(e){
    console.log("clicked1");
});
$('#border_wrap').trigger('click');
```

Comment: Thanks @keithics, I was doing blunder mistake which you have explained above.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>I thought that [**this demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/5R27Q/) would not work but it does (Chrome 12). It will `alert` two messages, one for each click event. One is created by jQuery and one is native but I thought that only jQuery events could be triggered.</strike>

**Edit:** Yes the `click` does not follow `href`.

**Edit 2:** So the event you want to manually trigger is actually an event created by a Prototype carousel plugin. For the code below I am assuming it is [this one](http://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/). If that is the case, why can't you just use [fire the event](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/element/fire) using Prototype or natively… like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        #carousel-wrapper {
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
            overflow:hidden;
            border:1px dashed red;
        }
        #carousel-content {
            width:500px;
        }
        #carousel-content .slide {
            float:left;
            width:100px;
            height:100px;
        }
    </style>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://prototype-carousel.googlecode.com/files/carousel-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/raw/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
        jQuery.noConflict();

        function fakeClick(event, anchorObj) {
          if (anchorObj.click) {
            anchorObj.click()
          } else if(document.createEvent) {
            if(event.target !== anchorObj) {
              var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
              evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window,
                  0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
              var allowDefault = anchorObj.dispatchEvent(evt);
              // you can check allowDefault for false to see if
              // any handler called evt.preventDefault().
              // Firefox will *not* redirect to anchorObj.href
              // for you. However every other browser will.
            }
          }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="carousel-wrapper">
    <div id="carousel-content">
        <div class="slide">1</div>
        <div class="slide">2</div>
        <div class="slide">3</div>
    </div>
</div>
<div>
    <a href="javascript:" class="carousel-jumper" rel="slide-1">Jump to slide 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:" class="carousel-control" rel="prev">Previous slide</a>
    <a href="javascript:" class="carousel-control" id="next" rel="next">Next slide</a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    new Carousel('carousel-wrapper', $$('#carousel-content .slide'), $$('a.carousel-control', 'a.carousel-jumper'));

    document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
//        $$('a[rel="next"]')[0].simulate('click');
        fakeClick(event, document.getElementById('next'));
    });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There are two examples in this demo of event firing (one is commented out but you can switch for the same result). One is from [Trigger an event with Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype/460695#460695) which uses [`event.simulate.js`](https://github.com/kangax/protolicious/raw/5b56fdafcd7d7662c9d648534225039b2e78e371/event.simulate.js) and one using the `fakeClick()` function from [How can I simulate a click to an anchor tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1421584/how-can-i-simulate-a-click-to-an-anchor-tag/1421968#1421968). Either of which is working for me in Chrome 12.

Comment: Thanks to all of you but still doesn't work even if I tried your various solutions..I don't really know.

If could help..the <a> element i'm trying to autoclick is the next button of a scriptaculous carousel..that maybe has autoclicking disabled by design ?? mmmmm..

Comment: Which carousel are you using?

Comment: It wasn't made by me, it's called from carousel.js and it's named as 'HP carousel"...

Comment: Why do you need to use jQuery if it's a Prototype carousel? Updated my answer with a potential solution, assuming you are using [prototype-carousel](http://code.google.com/p/prototype-carousel/).