# Simulating a link click in JQuery with Chrome - using both href and download

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, download, click

I have a Chrome extension that dynamically creates links and adds them to a webpage. The links download files. They each have a `download` attribute to name the files correctly (only works in Chrome, afaik - but it only needs to), as well as `href` for the url of the file. How can I simulate clicking one of these links?

I don't need to click the version within the document necessarily, just the link object.

Basically, how can I write, in Javascript/JQuery, code to have Chrome download a file named with `download` at the `href` location?

The JQuery `click()` command didn't seem to do anything, though I can't figure out why.

Comment: Do you delegate event? How do you bind your event?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Trigger click jquery not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5867370/trigger-click-jquery-not-working) (solution = use the native `click` method, `$('selector')[0].click()`)

Answer (score 2):

I know this thread is old, but it's the first result in search, so for others who seeks answer, here it is:

```
$(css_selector)[0].click();
```

And you're doing it $(function(){ **HERE** }); and some js functionality is added to css_selector on original page load, then maybe you want to delay **HERE** execution by setting timeout.

Answer (score 0):

you can try simulating the [click](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/click)
 like this

```
$("your_selector").trigger("click");
```

or like this

```
$("your_selector").click();
```

Comment: Neither of those seem to do anything and I can't figure out why. I checked out the selector and it is identifying the correct element, just no event is firing.