# How to trigger events (onclick) with specific orders in js/prototype

Tags: javascript, click, prototypejs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Trigger an event with Prototype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype)

example, 3 onclick events in javascript/prototype. How to force prototype to run alert functions for dump "first!", "second!" and then "third!" value. Thanks and here is code that you can c/p:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.2/prototype.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
  $("go").observe("click", function() { alert('First!'); });
  $("go").observe("click", function() { alert('Third!'); });
  $("go").observe("click", function() { alert('Second!'); });
  });
//]]>
</script>
<form>
<input id="go" type="button" value="Click me!"  />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: bind them in the right order ?

Comment: On IE order isn't relevant... Is there anything else I can do. Thanks

Comment: indeed pre-IE9 seems to not maintain order..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Event handlers are functions in JavaScript, and functions are prime citizens in JavaScript. Usually a middle object contains the list of all handlers as an array. For example, in jQuery, `data('events')` holds the event handlers. Unless prototype has an straightforward, you should manually fetch all handlers, order them up and assign them back.

Or

As @gaby has said, you can bind them using correct order in you markup at first place.

Comment: checking IE versions pre-9 the bound order is not maintained..

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var handlers = [func1, func2, func3];
$("go").observe("click", function() { 
    var i = 0, len = handlers.length;
    for(i; i<len;i++)
       handlers[i]();
});
```

There are improvements of course, but it's a general idea

Comment: Thanks on reply. It is good answer but not quite... I'm working with Magento and there I have button "submit" and Magento has something like $("go").observe("click", function()... Basically I want to create another "click" function which will trigger before Magento's. It's not right to access default behavior, so I want my onclick trigger before and then other "clicks" can be run... Thanks!