# Prevent other observers from being called with Prototype.js

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, dom-events

I have two observers registered via the `Event.observe` function of the Prototype JavaScript framework. Both observers observe the same event on the same element. The second observer is registered by a 3rd party library and it performs the real event handling. The first observer is my own observer. I want to check some condition inside and if the condition is met, I want to prevent the second observer from being called. Is there a way to achieve this? I have tried `event.stop()` and `return false` and it does not have the effect I am looking for.

```
element.observe(
    "myevent",
    function (event) {
        if (/* some condition*/) {
            /* the following attempts do not work really */
            event.stop();
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Both observers are observing the same event on the same element? You will run into a race condition as they both should be fired at the same time. The `event.stop()` method will only stop bubbling and propagation not another event that is in progress.

Comment: @geek-num-88 Does it mean that the order of observers on a single element is not deterministic or even that they can be fired in parallel?

Comment: I believe that is the case. A suggestion is if you chain the events together eg fire your event and if the condition fails/succeeds then fire the other event handler. You would have to disable the other event observer. Or `Event.stopObserving(element, eventName)` right before your observer definition

Comment: Fire my own event is not an option in my case. The event is fired by the library and observed by the library. I just want to keep this flow if the event is fired for the first time, but stop the event processing if it is fired for the second time.

Comment: Anyway, the observers seem to be called serially and in the order they were registered. However, I have not found any guarantee in documentation. This stack overflow question addresses the order issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6651408/how-to-trigger-events-onclick-with-specific-orders-in-js-prototype