# Selecting first option of multiple select elements by Prototype JS

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I want to select first option of all the select dropdowns having class `required-entry` in a page with Prototype JS. I have searched through SO questions and found many relevant questions but not what I exactly needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been quite a while since I've done any Prototype.js. So this may not be the best way to go about it, but it *should* work.

let's say you have a page with:

```
<select class='required-entry'>
    <option value='a'>AAA</option>
    <option value='b'>BBB</option>
    <option​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​ value='c'>CCC</option>
</select>

<select class='required-entry'>
    <option value='x'>XXX</option>
    <option value='y'>YYY</option>
    <option value='z'>ZZZ</option>
</select>​
```

You can grab the first `option` for each `select` by doing:

```
var firstOptions = [];

$$('.required-entry').each(function(sel, i) {
    firstOptions.push($(sel).getElementsBySelector('option')[0]);
});

// firstOptions is now an array containing the first options
```

Now, I couldn't tell from your question if you wanted to *retrieve* the first options, or set the `select` value so that the first option is literally *selected*. Here's the later:

```
$$('.required-entry').each(function(sel, i) {
    sel.selectedIndex = 0;
});
```

Comment: Yes I wanted to literally select the first option. Your script even selects the first option, but the function which should be triggered on change event is not getting called. Any ideas?

Comment: I think you could add a `.fire` for the `$(sel)` just before or after `sel.selectedIndex = 0;`

Comment: Okay, finally achieved it from the answer by Greg in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype . Thanks