# Trigger Real Event with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

It seems that jQuery's `trigger()` only runs event handlers that were bound with jQuery.  I have some modules that use native browser event binding.  Using the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/2676527 works for me, but I'm wondering if there's something built in to jQuery that will do this?

**Update from comments:**  apparently it works for click events on buttons.  But not for change events on select boxes: http://jsfiddle.net/qxpXV/2/

For the record: hacking the other library to do its bindings with jQuery **does** make `trigger()` work, but I don't really want to do that.

Comment: @singpolyma What do you mean by native browser event binding? `.addEventListener()`? I am able to invoke such a handler: http://jsfiddle.net/mnrUt/ Hm, even if I specify the code in via an `onevent` HTML attribute, jQuery's `.trigger()` is still able to run that code: http://jsfiddle.net/mnrUt/1/

Comment: @adeneo See my two demos above.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas - Seems it does work, always expected it to not work as the docs says it's for events bound with jQuery, and never really got around to test it !

Comment: @ŠimeVidas interesting that it works for click.  But not for change on a select box: http://jsfiddle.net/qxpXV/2/

Comment: @singpolyma Works for me on Chrome. May be browser-specific.

Comment: @duskwuff weird.  I just tested in the latest Chromium for my plaform and that also did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by manually firing/dispatching an event (depending on the browser, `fireEvent`/`dispatchEvent`) directly on the DOM element. Code [from this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2490825/1081234) will handle the event dispatching, you'll just need to execute it against a DOM element and not the jQuery wrapper.

Comment: Accepting this because it seems to be the only way.  jQuery just doesn't support this, as far as I can tell :)