# Jquery trigger works only for one event specified by addEventListener at a time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm building a library without depending on Jquery in order to better my javascript knowledge. However in writing tests for the library I'm using some Jquery methods.

I have a test that triggers events listeners added using the native `EventTarget.addEventListener` method using Jquery's `.trigger` method.

```
var elem = document.getElementById('square');
elem.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert('click');
});
elem.addEventListener('mouseover', function () {
   alert('mouseover');
});
$(elem).trigger('click');
$(elem).trigger('mouseover');
```

When I trigger two different events on the same element, only one handler fires.

This can be observed in this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v3rse/o0gt33aw/1/)

Can someone explain why this happens and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `addEventListener`, you can't use jQuery's `trigger` method. (It will work for some events like `click`, but not for everyone, like `mouseover`, as you noticed). This is also explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12698192/trigger-real-event-with-jquery?rq=1).

You have two options. Either you use jQuery's `on` event like this:

```
$(elem).on('mouseover', function () {
    alert('mouseover');
});
```

Or the other is to trigger the event without using jQuery. You can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490825/how-to-trigger-event-in-javascript) to do that.