# Trigger a change event for prototype.js with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs, jquery-events

I am dealing with a long prototype.js code that is activated by a 'change' event listener and I need to create a jQuery function that simulates a 'change' event to activate the prototype script. How can I do this?

note: `$('select[id="..."]').val(...).trigger('change');` does not activate the prototype script

Comment: Can't you trigger the event with prototype.js?

Comment: I do not know prototype.

Comment: It does not seem to be very difficult. Google lead me to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery's `.trigger()` only works for event handlers added via jQuery (see: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

> Any event handlers attached with .on() or one of its shortcut methods are triggered when the corresponding event occurs. They can be fired manually, however, with the .trigger() method.

Prototype's `.fire()` only works for custom events (see: http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Event/fire/)

> Fires a custom event of name eventName with element as its target. Custom events must include a colon (:) in their names.

Unfortunately, the only way to do what you're describing is to grab some kind of reference to the "long prototype.js code" and manually call it. (This would depend on what the implementation you are referring to looks like.) It's not possible to fire a true "native" change event using javascript.