# Simulating click and change with Prototype - Simulate.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, prototypejs

I have the following Prototype code acting as an observer and I'm trying to trigger off the observer, after setting the value of the select manually...

```
select.observe('change', this.onChange.bindAsEventListener(this));
```

I was originally trying to fire this off in a number of ways via jQuery, until I realized it wouldn't work. I then adopted the script, 'event.simulate.js' as outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/460644/trigger-an-event-with-prototype). The problem I'm now experiencing is that the console shows the following error...:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'simulate' of null scripts.js?v=56:701
```

I thought my code was correct...:

```
$('div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select').simulate('click');
```

The webpage (if it's helpful) can be seen [here.](http://store.tintworld.com/interior-exterior-accessories-lighting/wiper-blades/windshield-wiper-blade.html) I hope it's an easy fix, and would appreciate any and all guidance even if it is a suggestion on how to handle this differently.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `$()` method only selects via id so this statement

```
$('div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select').simulate('click');
```

is invalid - you can however do this

```
$$('div.amfinder-horizontal td:nth-child(1) select').first().simulate('click');
```

`$$()` is the CSS selector method which returns an array of elements that match the selector. then use `first()` or `[0]` to identify the first element (or only) in the array which you can then run the method `simulate()`